# Get key from a value(list) in a dic

Tags: python, dictionary, key-value

Is there a way to retrive a key from values if the values is a list:

```
def add(self, name, number):
        if name in self.bok.values():
            print 'The name alredy exists in the telefonbok.'
        else:
            self.bok.update({number: []})
            self.bok[number].append(name)
            print self.bok
```

This works if i only have one element in the list:

```
self.bok.keys()[self.bok.values().index(my value i want to get the corresponding key)]
```

But if i insert more elements is gives me the error that it isnt in the list, 
if u are wondering im creating an telephone book using class and dictionary so im supposed
to give and alias to the number and also be able to change the number on one name and alias should also get the new number. Would appriciate any help sorry if i'm blurry

Answer (score 0):

If you find yourself wondering "how do I look up a key by its value?" it usually means that your dictionary is going the wrong way, or at least that you should be keeping two dictionaries. This is **especially** true if you notice yourself ensuring that the values are unique by hand!

At the moment, your conditional is never true (unless `self.bok.values()` is updated some other way), because `name` is (presumably) a string whereas `self.bok.values()` looks like it's a list of lists. If names should only appear once in the telephone book, that's a good hint that you should have a dictionary going the opposite direction.

Assuming you also need the number-to-name lookup, what I would do is add another dictionary to your class, and update them both whenever you add a new name/number pair.

```
import collections # defaultdict is a very nice object

# elsewhere, presumably in the __init__ method
self.name_to_number = {}
self.number_to_names = collections.defaultdict(list)

def add(self, name, number):
    if name in self.name_to_number:
        print 'The name alredy exists in the telefonbok.'
    else:
        self.name_to_number[name] = number
        self.number_to_names[number].append(name)
```

If you're dead set on doing it the hard way for whatever reason, the `findByValue` method in [Óscar López's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19414025/2069350) is what you need.

Comment: @user2888098 You're writing the `add` function, yes? Just keep track of two dictionaries, one that maps numbers to names (this is what you have) and another that maps names to numbers. Update them both whenever you add a new name/number pair.

Comment: @user2888098 It's also worth noting that "immutable" is a slippery thing in Python. Lists certainly aren't immutable by any stretch of the imagination.

Comment: Its not really the number to name function i need its just that if i i have a name with a number, lets say peter with 555, then if i want to create and alias to peter, lets say trevor, trevor is gonna have the same phonenumber as peter. They are connected, (peter, trevor, 555). But if i change the number for Peter to 222 trevor also should get the number 222, do u get what i mean? :P

Comment: @user2888098 If all these things can be related/aliased, then you probably want to consider building a custom object to hold two lists of associated names/numbers, and then put *those* objects in a `set` or something for quick retrieval. However, it's easy enough to change all the related information using the schema I laid out in my answer. Just iterate over each related name and change its number. e.g. `def change_number(self, name, number): for na in self.numbers_to_names[self.names_to_numbers[name]]: self.names_to_numbers[na] = number`    
Too bad comments can't have line breaks. :-(

Comment: Yeah that sound about right creating an object, ill try to search for object and sets in google :) cause im working on object-oriented programming  atm at my university so that is the purpose